# Change drawable color on button on click

Tags: android, button, colors, onclick, drawable

I have some buttons with a text and a drawable set in the xml with `android:drawableLeft=...`

I want to know how to change, on click, the color of both the text and the drawable. And it has to be general, because i have a lot of button with each time, a different drawable.

My XML :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_articles"
        style="@style/Main_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green3"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="Articles"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_article"
        android:textColor="@drawable/btn_default" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_encaiss"
        style="@style/Main_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green4"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="Encaissement"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_encaiss"
        android:textColor="@drawable/btn_default" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_stats"
        style="@style/Main_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green1"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="Statistiques"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_stats"
        android:textColor="@drawable/btn_default" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clients"
        style="@style/Main_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@color/green2"
        android:onClick="myClickHandler"
        android:text="Clients"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clients"
        android:textColor="@drawable/btn_default" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For now i just change text color on click. I want to change both drawable and text color without knowing the left drawble name.

Comment: Paste the xml please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

With this code, you can change a left drawable programatically.

For the text color, please see [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)